# What does the square bracket mean in "map <string, int> instance[numberFeatures];"

Tags: c++, syntax, maps

What does the [numberFeatures] mean when initializing a map. I could not find the answer anywhere? Later in the code, it uses instance[i][temp] = j where i,j are ints and temp is a string. What does that mean as well?

I've looked up all map tutorials on the internet but none seem to include the [] notation

```
int numberFeatures; //number of features in the dataset
  string data;
  bool consistent;

  cin >> numberFeatures; //input the number of features

  vector <int> numberAttributes(numberFeatures); //number of attributes 
  for each feature.
  map <string, int> instance[numberFeatures+1];

  for(int i=0; i<numberFeatures; i++)
  {
    cin >> numberAttributes[i];

    for(int j=1; j<=numberAttributes[i]; j++)
    {
      string temp;
      cin>> temp;
      instance[i][temp] = j; //map attribute name with number
    }
  }

  instance[numberFeatures]["no"] = 0;
  instance[numberFeatures]["yes"] = 1;
```

Comment: What does `[some_integer]` do outside of the context of a `std::map`? For your second question, think about the first again, but also in the context of `std::map`.

Comment: 1.yes, thats what I'd like to know!
2. usually for maps, it would be instance["hello"] = 3; , right?

Comment: It means that the shown code is not standard C++. This is a variable-length array, which is not standard C++.

Comment: You'd be better off reading a book or tutorial resource than learning C++ language fundamentals from Stack Overflow questions. One of the requirements of a good question is that it is well researched. It can be hard to know what term to Google if you don't know what you're looking at, but reading some results from "C++ square brackets after variable" is enough.

Comment: The "standard" is the set of rules on how C++ works. All compilers are supposed to follow the rules of the standard. They can also add their own features that are outside of the standard. Different compilers add different ones, so using non-standard code means it may stop working when you compile somewhere else.

Comment: @R.Deeljore `map <string, int> instance[numberFeatures+1];` -- Whoever created this code also used `std::vector` elsewhere.  This is an indication that the writer of this code either 1) didn't know what the purpose of `std::vector` is, or 2) lazy and used non-standard C++, or 3) a combination of 1) and 2).  The code is not standard C++, and the solution would have been to use `std::vector<std::map<string, int>> instance(numberFeatures + 1);`

Comment: Also, seems bad practice to use a vector *and* a map (and also a C-style array of a map which is of non-standard variable size... that's not even checked), instead of creating a vector of a struct/class that holds the map. Also, "number of attributes for each feature" can be determined by the `size()` of the map, no need to do some bookkeeping on a separate vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the square bracket mean in “`map <string, int> instance[numberFeatures];`”

`Type name[N]` is a declaration of a variable. It declares an array of `N` objects of type `Type`. The size of an array variable (`N`) must be a compile time constant in C++ or else the program is ill-formed. `name` is the name of the variable.

`map <string, int>` is a type. `map <string, int> instance[numberFeatures];` is a declaration of an array of `numberFeatures` objects of type `map <string, int>`. The name of the variable is `instance`. However in the example, `numberFeatures+1` is not a compile time constant value, and so the example program is ill-formed.

> Later in the code, it uses instance[i][temp] = j where i,j are ints and temp is a string. What does that mean as well?

First the subscript operator is applied on the array. The result is a reference to the `i`th (zero based) element of the array.
Then subscript operator is applied on the resulting element. Since the element is of type `map <string, int>`, this invokes the overloaded subscript operator of the `map` template. Finally, `j` is assigned to the result of the second subscript operator.

Comment: How else do you declare arrays, @R.Deeljore?

Comment: Actually, I just thought that the [] was part of the declaration of the map in some way and not related to arrays. Now it seems kinda obvious. Usually I use int,string arrays etc... so I didnt think about it.